# Extracting texts from pdf files for building a model with Gensim

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, gensim

I would like to train a model with Gensim using news texts from electronic newspapers (in pdf format). What is the best way to extract texts from pdf files and to process the texts ready for training? Any sample codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract text on a per-page basis with [PyPDF2](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/). The simplest code would look something like this:

```
import PyPDF2

reader = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader("your_file.pdf")

for page in reader.pages:
    text = page.extractText()
    # do something with text
```